# Blackberry USB with C# Desktop

Tags: c#, blackberry

I'm searching a lot of time to find a sample or solve a Blackberry USB connection with C# desktop but i can't solve it.

So, Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It would be helpful if you could post what you have already tried and where it is that you are facing a problem.

Comment: Yes, this rather obscure problem with Blackberry USB connection with C# .net desktop can be solved by people at stackoverflow. However, it does require a little effort from you. Are you up for it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think you spent any time searching because this info is quite accessible. For instance:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Use_a_USB_or_serial_port_connection_508962_11.jsp

And in the JDE samples folder, you have a complete working demo in this path:

```
<JDE path>\samples\com\rim\samples\device\usbdemo
```

Comment: yeah, but the sample in C++ and i haven't experience with C++ so i asked with C#.net

Comment: The sample is written in Java. I understood that the PC side was written in C#. Actually that doesn't matter. The BlackBerry part has to be be coded in Java, unless you want to develop for the new BlackBerry PlayBook.

Comment: i mean the desktop sample was written in C++, not a blackberry sample.

Comment: Perhaps if you were a little more helpful with your original post and comments you would get better results